# Can't compile kernel in gentoo

Tags: compiling, linux-kernel, gentoo

I installed gentoo by the handbook from official site.
When I got into the step  7.b. *Installing the Sources*,
the book says:

> Code Listing 2.2: Viewing the kernel source symlink
>
> When you take a look in `/usr/src` you should see a symlink called `linux` pointing to your kernel source.

But in my VirtualBox, there is no such file, only a `linux-3..3.38-gentoo` directory in `src`. When I tried to use

```
cd  linux-3.3.38-gentoo
make menuconfig
```

this error occurred:

```
init/Kconfig:389: can't open file "kernel/irq/Kconfig"
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: `ls -l /usr/src/linux-3.3.38-gentoo/kernel/irq/Kconfig`?

Answer (score 4):

most of the kernel modules you will build expect `/usr/src/linux` to point to the sources of the kernel you want to build the module for, so the first thing to do here is to create that link:

```
ln -s /usr/src/linux-3.3.38-gentoo /usr/src/linux
```

Then try and configure your kernel the way you did it.

```
cd /usr/src/linux
make menuconfig
```

Note: Gentoo would have created this link for you if you had switched the USE flag `symlink` on for `sys-kernel/gentoo-sources`. You can tell Gentoo which USE flag should be turned on by package by adding an entry in the file `/etc/portage/package.use`.

Comment: In alternative to manually using `ln`, one can also use `eselect` with the `kernel` module. `eselect` is part of the `app-admin/eselect` package.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using gentoo-source and already in gentoo environment, the **app-admin/eselect** tool will help you do this:

```
eselect kernel list
```

and

```
eselect kernel set
```

And if you are not familiar with kernel installation **genkernel** can be very helpful. You might want to use *--config=* and *--menuconfig*, which is not documented in HandBook(HandBook is just a step-by-step guide form some dev's perspective, many tools it mentioned are **underestimated** by fresh readers).